# Using Three.js with WebStorm, module import not working

Tags: three.js, webstorm

Not usually a JS programmer. I setup a new WebStorm project, used npm to install three.js, everything looks fine, but when I try to import it the import statement is fine, but you can't use it, nothing is code completed.

Clearly I am missing something important. Three appears correctly in the `package.json` and lock json and I have all the files in the usual `node_modules`. Any use of the import THREE shows nothing. There are no errors, just warnings about the unused items and `WebGLRenderer` is undefined.

This is the default WebStorm setup with ECMAScript 6.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'three';
            function main()
            {
                const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
                const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
            }
        </script>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Webstorm made it work again. The app was running for a couple weeks, so perhaps there is memory leak or other issue.